# MySQL performance join on table itself

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Let there be a table containing events, with the following columns:

- eventId (integer)
- type (integer)
- timestamp (unix one)
- itemId (integer)
- userPrimaryId (is NULL if not present - integer)
- userSecondaryId (always present - string)
- data (contains various other information)

Now, let us also define event type 2 and event type 1.

The problem is to find all event with type 2:

- that have inside the Event table of type 1 (let us call this a validating event)
- that are within a time frame n form type 2 (that is the the validating event is less than the event 2, however not smaller than n from n in timestamp)
- event 2  and the validating event must match on itemId and (userPrimaryId if not this is not null, otherwise on the secondaryId)

and return the data field for such events, plus the data field of the validating row (this is important).

The real problem is to do this in a fast query, as there exists a couple hundred thousand rows for both event type 2 and type 1.

We have indexes on the eventId (primary key), type, and timestamp fields.

Here's where I stand:

```
  SELECT
  *
  FROM
  (
     SELECT
     *
     FROM Event
     WHERE type=2
     AND Time BETWEEN ${from} AND ${to}
  ) b
  INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT
     *
     FROM Event
     WHERE type=1
     AND Time BETWEEN (${from}-1000 AND ${to}
  ) c ON b.ItemId=c.ItemId
  AND ((b.UserId IS NOT NULL AND b.UserId=c.UserId) OR c.CookieId=b.CookieId)
```

My current approach is to select the two event types in two separate queries, inner join them.

Now my problem is that how to keep only that row that has the greatest timestamp if I group this by the eventId for type 2 elements.

Any great solutions, or alternate approaches for faster query execution? (the upper join takes around 100s to execute, which is already significant)

Comment: For your second to last paragraph, do you mean to group by `ItemId` or `eventId`? Each `eventId` can only have one `timestamp`, so it doesn't make sense to me to find the greatest timestamp for each `eventId`. Also, is `UserId` the same as `userPrimaryId` and is `CookieId` the same as `userSecondaryId`? The columns you listed up to differ from those in your sample query.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you absolutely must do is to rewrite this query without using `SELECT * FROM (subquery)`,
because so far MySql isn't smart enaugh and cannot push outer join predicates into the subqueries.
It just materialize both subqueries, and then join their results, what isn't an optimal approach.
You can see it easily on explain plan of this query, there will be 4 rows in the explain that looks more or less like this:

```
 ------- + ---------------- +
| id      | select_type      | 
+ ------- + ---------------- + 
| 1       | PRIMARY          |
| 1       | PRIMARY          | 
| 3       | DERIVED          | 
| 2       | DERIVED          | 
+ ------- + ---------------- +
```

The rewritten query is:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Event b
INNER JOIN Event c
ON b.ItemId=c.ItemId
  AND ((b.UserId IS NOT NULL AND b.UserId=c.UserId) OR c.CookieId=b.CookieId)
WHERE b.type=2
  AND b.Time BETWEEN ${from} AND ${to}
  AND c.type=1
  AND c.Time BETWEEN (${from}-1000 AND ${to}
```

After this you should get an explain that looks like this:

```
+ ------- + ---------------- +
| id      | select_type      | 
+ ------- + ---------------- + 
| 1       | SIMPLE           | 
| 1       | SIMPLE           |
+ ------- + ---------------- +
```

---

And in the end create this two-column index:

```
CREATE INDEX ev_type_tm ON event( type, time );
```

---

One remark:

In this condition:

```
AND ((b.UserId IS NOT NULL AND b.UserId=c.UserId)
```

the `b.UserId IS NOT NULL` is redundant and can be skipped,
since this part of the condition: `b.UserId=c.UserId` will evaluate to false (strictly speaking - to NULL, what is equivalent to false) when `b.UserId` or `c.UserId` is null.

Comment: So here's what I ended up using: 

SELECT  *
  FROM Event b
  INNER JOIN Event c
  ON b.ItemId=c.ItemId
    AND (b.UserId=c.UserId OR c.CookieId=b.CookieId)
  WHERE b.EventType=2
    AND b.Time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-02')*1000 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-03')*1000
    AND c.EventType=11
    AND c.Time BETWEEN b.Time AND b.Time-7*24*3600*1000;

id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE b range PRIMARY,IB_UserId_All PRIMARY 10 <null> 8576 Using where; Using join buffer
1 SIMPLE c ref PRIMARY,IB_UserId_All PRIMARY 2 const 395928 

It's painfully slow :(

Comment: Have you created the index I had mentioned in my answer ? Please post your tables structures including indexes definition. The explain shows that there is only one index `IB_UserId_All` (except the primary key).